# How to restore UIPopoverController with iOS State Restoration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller, state-restoration

In one of my apps I've implemented [state restoration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html) and am currently working on an iPad version. In the iPad version I'm using `UIPopoverController` for displaying view controllers, but I'm unable to find out how those popover controllers should be saved and restored.

`UIPopoverController` doesn't inherit from `UIViewController` and hence doesn't have `restorationIdentifier` and `restorationClass` properties I could make use of.

Am I responsible for saving the popover controller's `targetRect` and encoding it's `contentViewController` manually in my main view controller so I can restore it during its `-decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:` method or is there an easier way I just couldn't find in the documentation?

Fabain

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have a property `popoverControllerRestorationDictionary` for storing additional information about the popover controller currently being presented, here is an idea of how you could restore popover controllers:

```
- (void)presentPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController fromRect:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:animated];

    self.popoverControllerRestorationDictionary = @{ @"popoverController" : popoverController, @"rect" : [NSValue valueWithCGRect:rect] };
}

- (void)dismissedPresentedPopoverController
{
    self.popoverControllerRestorationDictionary = nil;
}

- (void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    ...

    if (self.popoverControllerRestorationDictionary != nil) {
        [coder encodeBool:YES forKey:@"restorePopoverController"];

        UIPopoverController *popoverController = [self.popoverControllerRestorationDictionary objectForKey:@"popoverController"];
        [coder encodeObject:popoverController.childViewController forKey:@"popoverController.childViewController"];

        NSValue *rectValue = [self.popoverControllerRestorationDictionary objectForKey:@"rect"];
        [coder encodeObject:rectValue forKey:@"popoverController.targetRect"];
    }
}

- (void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    ...

    if ([coder decodeObjectForKey:@"restorePopoverController"]) {
        UIViewController *childViewController = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"popoverController.childViewController"];
        CGRect targetRect = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"popoverController.targetRect"] CGRectValue];

        UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithChildViewController:childViewController];

        [self presentPopoverController:popoverController fromRect:targetRect animated:NO];
    }
}
```

This solution is suboptimal at best, so if anyone comes up with something better, please let me know!